# Twitter Search Api 1.1 ERROR: Could not cast value of type '__NSCFDictionary' to 'NSArray'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, twitter-oauth

This code is to search a hashtag on twitter but it gives error saying
**Could not cast value of type '__NSCFDictionary'  to 'NSArray'**

and the same code works fine when I access my home timeline with following URL
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json

```
func getTimeLine() {

    let accountType = account.accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier(
        ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter)

    self.account.requestAccessToAccountsWithType(accountType, options: nil,
        completion: {(success: Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in

            if success {
                let arrayOfAccounts =
                self.account.accountsWithAccountType(accountType)

                if arrayOfAccounts.count > 0 {

                    let twitterAccount = arrayOfAccounts.last as! ACAccount

                    let requestURL = NSURL(string:
                        "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23baseball&result_type=recent%3F")
                      let parameters = ["count" : "10"]

                    let postRequest = SLRequest(forServiceType:
                        SLServiceTypeTwitter,
                        requestMethod: SLRequestMethod.GET,
                        URL: requestURL,
                        parameters: nil)

                    postRequest.account = twitterAccount

                    postRequest.performRequestWithHandler(
                        {(responseData: NSData!, urlResponse: NSHTTPURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                            var err: NSError?
                            self.array = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableLeaves, error: &err) as! [AnyObject**strong text**]
                            if self.array.count != 0 {
                                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                                    self.mycollectionView.reloadData()
                                }
                            }
                    })
                }
            }
            else {
                println("Failed to access account")
            }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try making a cast to `NSDictionary`. It should solve your problem.

```
self.array = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(
    responseData,
    options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableLeaves, error: &err
) as! NSDictionary
```

Maybe this is the correct return from twitter.